# Carbon and Eloquent times

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I am trying to display all the entries entered within a specific time, from
27-02-2018 22:00:00 to 28-02-2018 05:59:59,
here is what I got so far, but i am not getting any results back from the webpage

```
$NightStart='22:00:00';
$NightEnd='05:59:59';
$dcmlogs = log::with('users')->whereBetween('created_at',['Carbon::today()->toDateString() $NightStart','Carbon::yesterday()->toDateString() $NightEnd'])->paginate(10);
```

Why I am not getting any results? I am sure there are some rows with these timestamps in the database.

Comment: You have `Carbon::today()` as a string under single quotations and aren't appending `$NightStart` or `$NightEnd` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php doesn't parse values inside `'` only inside `"`:

Try:

```
$NightStart = '22:00:00';
$NightEnd = '05:59:59';
$today = Carbon::today()->toDateString() . ' ' . $NightStart;
$yesterday = Carbon::yesterday()->toDateString() . ' ' . $NightEnd;
$dcmlogs = log::with('users')->whereBetween('created_at',[$yesterday, $today])->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$dcmlogs = log::with('users')->whereBetween('created_at',['Carbon::today()->toDateString() $NightStart','Carbon::yesterday()->toDateString() $NightEnd'])->paginate(10);
```

To:

```
$fromTime = Carbon::yesterday()->toDateString()." $NightEnd";
$toTime = Carbon::today()->toDateString()." $NightStart";

$dcmlogs = log::with('users')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromTime, $toTime])
    ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this entirely with Carbon you can use the following:

```
$dcmlogs = log::with('users')->whereBetween('created_at',[
    Carbon::yesterday()->hour(5)->minute(59)->second(59)->toDateTimeString(),
    Carbon::today()->hour(22)->toDateTimeString()
])->paginate(10);
```

Alternatively you can also use `setTime($h, $m, $s)` instead of manually setting conditions

```
$dcmlogs = log::with('users')->whereBetween('created_at',[
    Carbon::yesterday()->setTime(5, 59, 59)->toDateTimeString(),
    Carbon::today()->setTime(22, 0, 0)->toDateTimeString()
])->paginate(10);
```

Your example you were using single quotations which parses your conditions as a string and also wasn't appending properly.